# Can I get Notepad++-style vertical selection with arrow keys in Sublime or Atom?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, notepad++, text-editors, sublime-text-3, atom-editor

In Notepad++, I'm used to using <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>/<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> to put expand the cursor across multiple lines in a vertical line or rectangular selection. I think Visual Studio does something similar.

I'm trying Sublime and Atom instead. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>click</kbd>, and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>click + drag</kbd> are very cool, but I miss using the arrow keys to make my vertical selections.

Is there a way to do vertical/rectangle selects in Sublime Text 3 or Atom with the arrow keys? I'm open to installing packages.

#### Example

1. Say I have this (`│` represents the cursor, ignore the spaces in that column):

   ```
   x = os│.join(a, b)
   y = os .join(b, c)
   z = os .join(c, d)
   ```
2. I realize I forgot the module name, so I hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd>+<kbd>↓</kbd> and have:

   ```
   x = os│.join(a, b)
   y = os│.join(a, b)
   z = os│.join(a, b)
   ```
3. I type `.path` and now I have:

   ```
   x = os.path│.join(a, b)
   y = os.path│.join(a, b)
   z = os.path│.join(a, b)
   ```

I'd like to do the second step in Sublime Text 3 or Atom.

Comment: The corresponding Sublime Text keybindings on windows are `ctrl+alt+up/down`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sublime Text has this feature in built and it's called Column Selection functionality. It's super simple: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>↑</kbd>/<kbd>↓</kbd>

Or, if you have a middle mouse button, just middle click and drag (in Windows and macOS).

[Documentation](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/column_selection.html)

Answer (score 1):

In Atom, you can install the [`multi-cursor`](https://atom.io/packages/multi-cursor) which works exactly like Notepad++.

I'm not sure about Sublime Text, but take a look at the [MarkAndMove](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/MarkAndMove) or [PowerCursor](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PowerCursors) packages.